# matSuffix not working when wrapped inside of matFormField

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, mat-form-field

I am currently trying to write a global datepicker. For that I created a component observing the given example from angular (https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control). I only want to outsource a part of the whole mat-form-field, so this what I was doing:

*app.component.html:*

```
  <mat-form-field color="accent" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Date of Birth</mat-label>
    <my-date-picker formControlName="birthday"></my-date-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

*my-date-picker.component.html:*

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="TT.MM.JJJJ" [ngModel]="value"
  (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

(I think the .ts shouldn't be important for my problem)

But now it looks like this:

[image]

This also happens if I would wrap it like this in the app.component.html:

```
  <mat-form-field color="accent" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Date of Birth</mat-label>
    <div>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="TT.MM.JJJJ" [ngModel]="value"
      (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Because then it renders the matSuffix as part of the mat-infix. **So it seems like the matSuffix is not recognized correctly.**
[image]

Whilst it would render it like this without the extra wrapper (divs):
[image]

Putting:

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

in the app.component.html is not an option. I tried this and this just leads to other errors, which are worse than the css error.

Answer (score 1):

So I found that matSuffix only works on direct descendants and couldn't find any workaround for my case. It seems to be an open "issue" up to this day. Actually, it should be the expected behaviour, though a lot of people seem to struggle with it.

I solved this, by using a directive instead of a wrapper component. The directive listens to events like *keydown* and *change* to validate the date input and also sets the placeholder so every date-picker that uses this directive already has the placeholder I want.

If anybody has an actual solution to the above problem, please feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

<mat-datepicker-toggle **style="float: right"** matIconSuffix [for]="picker">